# Error al mostrar datos de BD en Java

Tags: java, mariadb

Tengo lo siguiente:

**Principal**

```
 public Principal() {
        tabla = new DefaultTableModel(null, getColumnas());
        setFilas();
        initComponents();
    }

    private String[] getColumnas(){
        String columna[]= new String[]{"titulo","descripcion","observacion","tipo"};
        return columna;
    }
    private void setFilas(){

        try{
            String consulta = "Select titulo_incidencia, decripcion_incidencia, observcion,tipo from incidencias";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.conexionBD().prepareStatement(consulta);
            ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();

            Object datos[] = new Object[4];
            while(res.next()){
            for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
                   datos[i] = res.getObject(i+1);
            }
            tabla.addRow(datos);
            }
            res.close();
        } catch(SQLException ex){
          Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

**Conexión**

```
public class MariaDBConexion {


    static String user="root";
    static String pass="xxxx";
    static String url="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/asistente";
    public Connection con = null;

    public Connection conexionBD(){
        try {

            try {
                 Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"); 
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error al registrar el driver de MariaDB: " + ex);
            }
           Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                url, user, pass);  
            boolean valid = connection.isValid(50000);
            System.out.println(valid ? "Conexión exitosa" : "conexión fallida");
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + sqle);
        }
    return con;
    }
```

Al ejecutarlo me salta lo siguiente:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at ayudantesistemas.Principal.setFilas(Principal.java:36)

En esta línea:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = con.conexionBD().prepareStatement(consulta);
```

¿Me podrían decir mi error?

Answer (score 2):

En la clase `MariaDBConexion`, al final del método `conexionBD()`, ejecutas la sentencia siguiente:

```
return con;
```

pero `con` es una variable global que aparentemente está en `null`. Lo más probable es que quisiste hacer:

```
return connection;
```

Sería bueno entender por qué existe esa variable global `con` que está causando confusión. Probablemente debes quitarlo completamente.

Comment: Gracias, le has dado al blanco, ya coloqué mi respuesta y espera a que junte 15 pts para que veas el +1 xD, gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la respuesta de @sstan, he cambiado de:

```
 Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                url, user, pass);
```

**a**

```
  con =  DriverManager.getConnection(  
                url, user, pass);
```

Anteriormente obtenía **`null`** ya que la variable global **`con`** tiene ese valor por defecto y va a cambiar su valor pasándole los parámetros de conexión, pero ya con el cambio que hice ya me funciona correctamente.